# Is that possible to count number of specific columns in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have a table like this:

[image]

Is that possible to return the number of rules that pass or fail based on the no?

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  no,
  case when rule1 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when rule2 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when rule3 = 'P' then 1 else 0 end as passes,
  case when rule1 = 'F' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when rule2 = 'F' then 1 else 0 end +
  case when rule3 = 'F' then 1 else 0 end as fails
from
  table
;
```

Comment: Thanks Balazs, it works perfectly!